# Laravel function that registered at controller always triggered, how to trigger it after I click a button

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So I found before I trigger my function in controller to updating data, the data get update without I clicked the button first. I also try delay it with `sleep()` but it always triggered first.

I want to calculate data with the disable column value false, and after being calculate in **score()** function, the return value from the calculate function saved in database, and then trigger button to update disable column to being true with **update()** function(so the data that have been calculate not being calculate again)

my controller : 
function to get data to being calculate :

```
public function getShowResultOfQuiz($id){      
            History::create([
                'user_id'=>$user,
                'jenis_quiz_id'=>$id,
                'score'=> $score,
                'kelas' => $kelas,
                'instansi' => $instansi
            ]); 
                $categoryquiz= JenisQuiz::find($id);
                $user=Auth::user()->id;



                $score=0;
                $score=$this->score(); // function to calculate data



                $kelas = Auth::user()->kelas;
                $instansi = Auth::user()->instansi;

                    switch ($id) {
                        case '1':
                        return view('user.pages.quizresult',compact('score','categoryquiz','sarans','answers'));

                        break;

                        case '2':
                        return view('user.pages.quizanxietyresult',compact('score','categoryquiz','answers','sarans'));
                        break;

                        case '3':
                        return view('user.pages.quizdepresiresult',compact('score','categoryquiz','$answers','$sarans'));
                        break;
                    }

                }
```

function to calculate the data :

```
public function score(){

    $user_data = Auth::user();
    $answers = $user_data->answer()->select('user_answer')->where('disable','=',false)->get();

               $a=0;
    $b = 0;
    $c = 0;
    if($answers->count()) {
        foreach ($answers as $answer) {
            switch ($answer->user_answer) {
                case 1:
                $a++;
                break;
                case 2:
                $b++;
                break;
                case 3:
                $c++;   
                break;
            }
        }

    }
    return $a+$b+$c;
}
```

function to update :

```
public function update(){
                sleep(30);
                $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
                        $user_data = User::find($user_id);
                        $answers_update = $user_data->answer()->whereDisable(false);
                        $answers_update->update(array("disable" => true));
            }
```

And when I'm inside view `user.pages.quizresult` there is an button to trigger update function

expect : call data answer with disable value false -> calculate it in score function -> save score in database-> turn disable data value = true

problem : turn data disable true -> answer data can't get by score function

Comment: You need two controller functions: 1) to render the page (GET) and 2) to update your data (POST). Do you have two separate routes?

Comment: This question seems to make some assumptions which are hard for me to understand: You are talking about a button click, but only show us code running on the server. The delay raises even more questions.

Comment: yes i have get route for the view, and get too for the update, why it's supposed to be post instead of get? @party-ring

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention the view page with button to trigger the update function, the button i used :
`<button id="update" onclick="location.href='{{action('QuizDataController@update')}}';" class="btn btn-primary">
                            Reset data untuk lanjut ke tes anxiety
                        </button>` 
@Thomas

Comment: It can be a GET, really depends if you're submitting anything else :) if you only call your update function in QuizDataController@update and do not call it anywhere else (QuizDataController@update isn't being called by anything other than your button) then I don't see why you should be getting any issues

Comment: You're calling `$score=$this->score();` in your route to render the page with the button on, which is why it is updating

Comment: yea,the QuizDataController@update just being called with my button :) so the return of my score affect to render the page instead of inserting the data first ?  @party-ring

Comment: `$score=$this->score(); // function to calculate data` is being called in `getShowResultOfQuiz`, I've posted an answer for you. I imagine `getShowResultOfQuiz` is called somewhere else other than your button i.e. your route?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your update score method in your method which renders your view with your button, meaning that every time you load the page you are updating the score, rather than only when the button is pressed.

```
public function update()
{
    // your function, no need for sleep now
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $user_data = User::find($user_id);
    $answers_update = $user_data->answer()->whereDisable(false);
    $answers_update->update(array("disable" => true));

    // redirect to your route for getShowResultOfQuiz
    return Redirect::route('your.route', $whicheverIDThisShouldBe);
}
```

This will redirect back to your main route and render your page as you expect. Remove the call to $this->update in `getShowResultOfQuiz`.

Comment: A little extra info for you: calling `sleep` wouldn't work because the function itself would sleep before carrying on completing your function. So it would sleep in the function and then carry on with loading your view. Calling sleep would just cause a delay in the page load time.

Comment: its work to not updating when it go to the result page, but when i hit the button reset, it updating  score to 0 because disable column change to true(i just make score calculate the answer with column disable false), how to make the button not updating the score , just update the disable column to be false,because if i not hit the button , when i take quiz again, the score from second try will be stack up with previous one,  thanks for answering :))  @party-ring